# Can't run ios app on simulator - "choose destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I am getting an error when trying to run my application on the IOS Simulator. I can run the application on my iPod and iPad, but any simulated device fails. It reads:
"Xcode cannot run using the selected device. Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device"

In the combined build settings, the existing Architectures field in build settings is set to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and it fails. I tried the other two options, "Standard architectures(armv7, armv7s)" and "Standard architectures (including 64-bit)(armv7,armv7s,arm64) and they still fail. Valid architectures is set to "arm64 armv7 armv7s" and it is using the Default compiler (Apple LLVM5.0).

I have tried restarting/removing plist/many other things and it still fails. I have all my developer profiles set. Creating new projects, such as SpriteKit Game, work fine in the simulator.

Any guidance as to what is causing my issue?  I have seen a number of people with the same issue, but I am clearly missing something because the solutions that work for them don't seem to work for me.

Using xcode 5.0.2
IOS Simulator Version 7.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.Window -> Organizer.
2.Click on device tab.
3.Click on the iOS device on the left side and click the button 'Use for development'.

more help available in below link..

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Running_Your_iOS_Application_on_an_iOS_Device

Comment: I am trying to run on the simulator, not a real device.  I already had it working on real devices.